# .wrl(VRML) to .mat conversion

Tags: matlab

I need a matlab function or code which converts a  .wrl file to . mat file , I just want to get vertices of shape and texture. The .wrl file can be both in (VRML or ARML2) the code should be able to give me the x,y,z vertices of shape and texture.

Comment: So look on Matlab's File Exchange (or whatever it's called).  SO doesn't provide code nor searches for code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I it would be better if you guide about a code or function.